# Add CSS Class Conditionally - Asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have gone through some posts with similar question but haven't find any good solution yet.

I am trying to add a css class in a `div` by checking that if there exists any error or not. Like below

```
<div class="form-group m-t-20 @((@Html.ValidationMessage("Email") != null && @Html.ValidationMessage("Email").ToString() != "") ? "has-danger has-error" : "")">
```

But when I do inspect-element then it seems that `@Html.ValidationMessage("Email")` is never empty (so `has-danger has-error` is always added) even though there is not validation message for `Email`, like

`@Html.ValidationMessage("Email")` translated to `<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Email" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>`

So is there a way to check if certain error is present then add a css class ? Also I would apperciate that I donot need to create new class (`.cs` file) for this small purpose.

PS: I am using Asp.net MVC. And at back-end I add error like this `ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "User already exists");`

Comment: Why not just use the class names that already are added - `field-validation-valid` (if its valid) and `field-validation-error` (if its not)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to add custom css class to `div`, my structure is `<div class="custom-class"><input /></div>`. Does class name matter here ?

Comment: What is the purpose? Why not just style the `field-validation-error` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to check errors in your model on View you should check `ViewData.ModelState` property.

Like this:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors.Count > 0))
{
   <span>your message<span/>
}
```

Ternary version:

```
@((!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors.Count > 0)? "your message": String.Empty)
```

Comment: On `IsValidField` its giving me error `Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary<HospitalManagament.Models.SignupModel>' does not contain a definition for 'IsValidField' and no extension method 'IsValidField' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary<HospitalManagament.Models.SignupModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @Junaid what version of MVC do you use?

Comment: I am using `v5.2.3.0`.

Comment: I tried your solution, but its still adding `has-danger has-error` in both cases (error and no-error).

Comment: @Junaid and what's exactly inside ViewData.ModelState["Email"] with and withour error? Maby you should just ckeck in on String.Empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147822/discussion-between-junaid-and-teo-van-kot).

Comment: I used `!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid && ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors.Count > 0`. It worked.

Comment: @Junaid you're the best! Updated